i have using eclipse java maven project this error was coming
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @5889fc44
Please help me and reslove the error
